# Likelihood ratio test for nested model

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, chi-squared-distribution

I'm having a question about a likelihood ratio test in favor of the simpler, nested model. Assume we have a complex model $M_1=(\alpha, \beta)$, that correctly describes the data, and another, nested model $M_0=(\alpha=x, \beta)$. We fit both models, and now, we want to know whether the simpler model $M_0$ is a good approximation of the real fit given by $M_1$.

I understand that according to Wilk's theorem the likelihood ratio follows a $\chi^2(df=1)$ distribution and that we can dismiss the null hypothesis if the likelihood ratio is big enough. But does that also work for dismissing the alternative hypothesis if the likelihood ratio in small enough? For example when the CDF of the $\chi^2$ is smaller than 0.05?

If not, what would be a correct way to test for that?

Comment: What is p-value? If it is greater than, say, 0.05. You have no evidence to reject the H0. In this case, you can choose the simpler model. If it is less than 0.05, you may need to choose the more complex model.

Comment: My issue is whether this approach is even correct. Usually, in a hypothesis test, you dismiss the null hypothesis if the p-value is small enough. With Wilk's theorem, that would be the case if the likelihood ratio is above a certain threshold (right side of the distribution). Now I would like to rule in favor of the null hypothesis by looking at the other (left-hand) side of the distribution. Does that help to understand the question?